# Create multiple virtual machine instances in azure using java SDK without Scale Set

Tags: java, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

I am using [java sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java) for creating virtual machines in windows azure.But i can create only one instance of virtual machine at a time.  
I can use Scale Set for creating multiple virtual machine instances but i am not suppose to do that, because Scale Set is a special image. If we created virtual machines using scale set it won't be displayed under virtual machines tab.  
So is there any way to create multiple virtual machine instances in azure using java SDK without using thread,loops and Scale Set?

Comment: Can you explain why not displaying scale set VMs under the virtual machines tab is a problem? You can see scale set VMs under the Scale Sets tab. It would be useful to understand this so we can understand whether to make changes to the VM tab in the portal.

Comment: We need separate virtual machines. If we create virtual machines using scale set this virtual machines were displayed under scale set but not under virtual machines tab.

Comment: Why is displaying under scale sets and not virtual machines tab a problem? If it's just a case of where the information is displayed I don't understand why that is an issue. Is there something specific about being a scale set VM that causes a problem for your app?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to separately create multiple VM instances at a time, and not using concurrent programming or creating one by one.

I think it's impossble for doing in a Java client with SDK without Scale Set.

Perhaps, you can try to use Azure Batch Service to run a Java job this parallelly, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/batch/ to know it. And there is a batch sample at https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently we are using aws for our project. The aws sdk supports creation of multiple vm instances at a time. We are trying to do the same with azure. But batch service does not do the same i guess.

Comment: @Karthi, Azure Batch certainly does support creating multiple VM instances at the same time and there exists a Java SDK. This concept is called a Compute Pool. Please follow [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-technical-overview/) for a technical overview of Azure Batch.